# Find records not in another table

Tags: mysql, plsql

I have a question and would be grateful if anyone could help.

I have two tables (REPL_SEND  and Repl_Finish both having 4 columns

```
UID (varchar)
reportID (varchar)
reportIDVersion (varchar)
replSendDTM (datetime)
```

*UID is different in both tables(it is primary key for tables)*

They can have duplicate value in `ReportId` and `reportIDVersion`.

I want `reportID/reportIDVersion` from `REPL_SEND` such that such combination of `reportID/reportIDVersion` is not present in `Repl_Finish`.

What I tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM REPL_SEND (nolock) 
WHERE reportID NOT IN (SELECT reportID FROM Repl_Finish)
```

This returns around 12000 records. But when I tried

```
SELECT t1.reportID
FROM REPL_SEND t1 (nolock)
LEFT JOIN Repl_Finish t2 (nolock) ON t2.reportID = t1.reportID
```

I am not getting any values (I mean DB is taking really long time, still executing after 15 minute)

**Question #1:** Is my first query correct? [Main Question]

**Question #2:** Why is it taking so much time with second query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question 1 :

```
SELECT *
FROM REPL_SEND (nolock) WHERE UID NOT IN
(SELECT rs.UID FROM 
     Repl_Finish as rf, REPL_SEND as rs
     where rf.reportID = rs.reportID 
     and rf.reportIDVersion = rs.reportIDVersion 

)
```

Question 2 : Maybe you need to add index on reportID and reportIDVersion columns in both tables

Comment: my apologies.UID is different in both table.UID is different primary key for tables